# Several subprojects. duplicate symbols for architecture

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I have a workspace with several projects of reusable artifacts, which are compiled into static libraries. Later, I'm using these libraries in other projects by including them as a sub-projects by reference. But I've faced problem of "duplicate symbols" when project A uses libraries B and C, which are both using library D (libraries B and C included as a sub-projects to project A, and all libraries B,C,D are from artifacts workspace). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to the sources of these static libraries you can't do anything. In case you do, you have to refactor/rename the class names that are clashing.

Comment: is there any design workaround for this issue? isn't it common that in artifacts workspace several libraries can include same libraries?

Comment: I don't think so, or at least I don't know any... For instance, if you take a look into UrbanAirship's library they renamed ASIHTTPRequest: https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/tree/master/Airship/External/UA_asi-http-request

Comment: well, I've found quite decent solution for that, with wich I'm fully satisfied. here it is: just create new project - static library in artifacts workspace called Artifacts and link it against all the other libraries (B,C,D) in workspace. at the same time, don't link B and C against D, but just set it as target dependency for them. result: in new project just link it against Artifacts library and include it as a sub-project. everything works now!